# Realtime geolocation tracking via realtime service provider

Tags: laravel, google-maps, real-time, pusher

I want to make a map marker which will move whenever it gets updates from server. Each map marker is described by a latitude and longitude.

```
  var url = '/tracking/records/fetch'+ '&id=' + user_id +'&type='+type;
```

This endpoint returns a set of `latitude,longitude` in JSON format.

How to move the marker when browser get updates from server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your `/tracking/records/fetch` endpoint is set up for polling: your webpage can repeatedly fetch a whole set of coordinates from the server, then update a map view of those coordinates. To make this realtime, you need to move away from pure polling to *pushing*.

First, [sign up for a Pusher account](https://pusher.com). Then have your webpage connect to your Pusher app and subscribe to a channel for new coordinates:

```
<script src="//js.pusher.com/4.0/pusher.min.js"></script>
<script>
var pusher = new Pusher('YOUR_APP_KEY', {
  cluster: 'YOUR_APP_CLUSTER'
});
var tracking-records = pusher.subscribe('tracking-records-' + type + '-' + user_id);  // Channel specific to this user
tracking-records.bind('new-tracking-record', function(data) {
  console.log('A new tracking record with latitude', data.latitude, 'and longitude', data.longitude);
  // Update your Google Map view here using data.latitude, data.longitude
});
</script>
```

Then on your server, identify where the tracking records are created (probably a database insert). At that point, publish the new coordinate to the `tracking-records` channel. Here's an example in Node.js:

```
var Pusher = require('pusher');

var pusher = new Pusher({
  appId: 'APP_ID',
  key: 'APP_KEY',
  secret: 'APP_SECRET',
  cluster: 'APP_CLUSTER'
});

pusher.trigger(
  'tracking-records-' + type + '-' + user_id,  // The channel name
  'new-tracking-record',  // The event type
  {latitude: 51, longitude: 3}  // The coordinate data
);
```

For more detailed examples, Pusher have a tutorial on [how to track our pizza in realtime with Pusher and Google Maps](https://blog.pusher.com/track-pizza-realtime-pusher-google-maps/), and another tutorial on [how to build a realtime map using Laravel](https://blog.pusher.com/build-realtime-map-laravel/).